# Sort 2D String Array with respect to a column in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have String array which has 3 columns (id, name, city), I want to sort the array in ascending order with respect to ***name*** column. Please help me with this.

```
String[][] array1 = {{"54","jim","delhi"},
                     {"67","dwight","bangalore"},
                     {"39","pam","pune"}};
```

Expected output should be:

```
array1 = {{"67","dwight","bangalore"},
          {"54","jim","delhi"},
          {"39","pam","pune"}};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stream` and `Comparator` Then you could sort that array how ever you want :

```
String[][] array1 = {{"54", "jim", "delhi"},
        {"67", "dwight", "bangalore"},
        {"39", "pam", "pune"}};


List<String[]> collect1 = Arrays.stream(array1).sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a[1])).collect(Collectors.toList());
String[][] sortedArray = new String[array1.length][3];
for (int i = 0; i < collect1.size(); i++) {
    sortedArray[i] = collect1.get(i);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sortedArray));
```